# Eloquent Sub-Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, subquery

I'm having some trouble writing a sub-query with Laravel's Eloquent ORM.

How could I turn this into one single query?

```
         $teams = Team::with(['owner'])
            ->get()
            ->sortBy(function ($team) {
         })
         ->values();

        foreach($teams as $team) {
            if ($team->owner_id === null) {
                $team['invitation'] = \Laravel\Spark\Invitation::where('team_id', $team->id)->first();
            }
        }
```

When I query the teams table, I want to be able to see if the `owner_id` is `null` and if it is, query the `Invitations` table and grab the invitation that is associated with the team.

I've read through the docs and did not see much about sub-queries.

Thanks,

Comment: Check out relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your relationships defined correctly you could do it like this:

```
$invitations = Invitation::with(['team', function($query) {
    $query->where('owner_id', null);
}])->get();
```

Alternatively you could just do the following and loop through them:

```
$teams = Team::where('owner_id', null)->get();
```

Comment: Then just use the relationship instead of the query. That way you can just call `$team->invitation` to get your invitation.